# Breaking down the format of the "Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling" EXIF tag

Tags: metadata, jpeg, exiftool, ycbcr

When using `exiftool` to inspect various images, I've seen lots of different values for the `Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling` tag. A few examples:

- `YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1)`
- `YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)`

In [How is the YCbCr color space represented in a JPEG image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/how-is-the-ycbcr-color-space-represented-in-a-jpeg-image), the meaning of *part* of this tag's values is explained, but not the whole thing: specifically, it explains the ratios (the `4:4:4` and `4:2:0` parts in my examples) but not the values in parentheses that follow them. I haven't been able to find documentation *anywhere* about what the full format of this field actually means, much less just the values in parentheses. It's possible that there is no formal spec for this field, and it comes down to the hardware and software used to produce the image file, but I have never seen an example in my research where `exiftool` did not output the field formatted in this way (nor does their [source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aexiftool%2Fexiftool%20%22Y%20Cb%20Cr%20Sub%20Sampling%22%20&type=code) seem to have any examples that show otherwise in their test fixtures that would imply it's not a *de facto* standard format.)

Could someone explain what each numeric value in this EXIF tag means? I'd ask for just an explanation of the values in parentheses since those are the ones I specifically don't understand, but I think that a full explanation would be useful for people searching for more info on this from a web search.

Comment: Fairly well explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). However , a photography context, halved chroma is noted as `4:2:2` independently of its direction (instead of `4:2:2` and `4:4:0`) so I suspect that the numbers in parentheses are just telling the H and V sampling factors (and are important and different only for halved chroma).

Comment: @xenoid thank you for the hypothesis. My guess is you're either mostly or completely right. Still, I was hoping to get a more authoritative answer. Wikipedia explains the same stuff the linked question does, but it doesn't explain the format of this field, not even in the articles about how JPEG represents subsampling. If you ever find any reference that confirms your hypothesis, please do write it up as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.